# Wifi constantly disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

I am using Kubuntu 23.04 and have been having trying to fix this issue for the past couple weeks. As you can imagine, I've read tons of threads on here and other places but no luck so far.

My wifi consistently disconnects, and then the SSID disappears the list, before reappearing and reconnecting. And then the process repeats. No other device I have has this problem so its not the network/router.

So far I've tried:

- Turning powersave off
- Forcing IPV4
- Swapping wifi card for Intel AX200
- Swapping router
- Changing SSID
- Fresh install

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MOTOROLA-8232C"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 94:18:65:4D:14:52   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:13   Missed beacon:0
```

Output of `journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` during the time of disconnection & reconnection:

```
Oct 04 15:33:45 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458825.0912] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 04 15:33:45 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458825.0912] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 04 15:33:45 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458825.1496] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 04 15:33:45 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458825.1496] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 04 15:33:47 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458827.6576] audit: op="statistics" interface="wlp6s0" ifindex=3 args="2000" pid=1775 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct 04 15:33:47 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458827.6873] audit: op="statistics" interface="wlp6s0" ifindex=3 args="500" pid=5629 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <warn>  [1696458839.9506] device (wlp6s0): link timed out.
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458839.9510] device (wlp6s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458839.9512] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <warn>  [1696458839.9516] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MOTOROLA-8232C'
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458839.9523] device (wlp6s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458839.9657] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458839.9657] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 04 15:33:59 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458839.9658] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): state changed no lease
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4923] policy: auto-activating connection 'MOTOROLA-8232C' (1e2cb19d-9048-43d1-9d0b-6b9cd18c85d4)
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4926] device (wlp6s0): Activation: starting connection 'MOTOROLA-8232C' (1e2cb19d-9048-43d1-9d0b-6b9cd18c85d4)
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4926] device (wlp6s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4927] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4928] device (wlp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4929] device (wlp6s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MOTOROLA-8232C' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4929] device (wlp6s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.4930] sup-iface[fde25a98111cffd3,0,wlp6s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5004] device (wlp6s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5006] device (wlp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5008] device (wlp6s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MOTOROLA-8232C' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5008] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MOTOROLA-8232C'
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5008] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5008] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5009] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5009] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5009] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5430] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5430] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5510] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5510] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5839] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.5839] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.6675] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.6675] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.7278] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.7278] device (wlp6s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MOTOROLA-8232C"
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.7279] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.7280] device (wlp6s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:27 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458867.7282] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 04 15:34:30 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458870.9746] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.34
Oct 04 15:34:30 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458870.9749] policy: set 'MOTOROLA-8232C' (wlp6s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 04 15:34:30 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458870.9784] device (wlp6s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:31 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458871.0199] device (wlp6s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:31 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458871.0200] device (wlp6s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 04 15:34:31 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458871.0201] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 04 15:34:31 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458871.0206] device (wlp6s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 04 15:34:31 Rare-AORUS NetworkManager[1146]: <info>  [1696458871.0209] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

I'm not sure if this may be a clue somehow, but when this happens the SSID disappers from ALL of my other devices wifi lists as well, unless they are already connected. Sometimes they will disconnect as well, but not always.

I know its a lot, but any help would be greaty appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @guiverc My bad. It is Kubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your router keeps changing channels every short period of time. Other devices may have mobile data and switch to it when there is no internet. You could get the IP address on your router and try to change the router's settings so that it doesn't keep changing channels so often. If that doesn't fix the issue, then there might be another problem that doesn't have to do with the router itself. If you were wondering how to change the router's settings, you have to put your router's ip (ej. 192.168.000.1) and inputting your password.

Comment: In my routers settings, there is an option to change the channel from `auto` to anything from 1-11. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Exactly! My router used to change channels constantly so i switched to something else that wasn't auto. That fixed my problem.

Comment: Switching to a fixed channel did not make a difference. Thank you for your input anyways.